# UITableView Delegate Assignment EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, uitableview, delegates

My iphone program has a Xib view with a tableview dropped in. I've subclassed UITableViewController and am trying to make the UITableView in the xib send it messages. The program crashes when I touch a tableview row.

It properly calls:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}
```

and the cell.textLabel.text is assigned properly.

Interface snippet:

```
@interface PlayersDrawsViewController : UIViewController {
    UITableView *uitableView;
    PlayersToDrawTableViewController *pvc;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *uitableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet PlayersToDrawTableViewController *pvc;
```

Implementation snippet:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Setup TableView
    if (pvc == nil) {
        pvc = [[PlayersToDrawTableViewController alloc]
               initWithNibName:@"PlayersToDrawTableViewController" bundle:nil];
        /* works great, loads rows */
        self.uitableView.dataSource = pvc.tableView.dataSource;
        /* EXC_BAD_ACCESS when didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called */
        //self.tableView.delegate = pvc;

    }
}
```

My UITableViewController Subclass:

```
@interface PlayersToDrawTableViewController : UITableViewController 
    <UITableViewDelegate>
    {
    }

    @end
```

**How can I get the delegate hooked up so it doesn't crash sending messages?**

I've read these threads and either I'm dense or they don't answer my question:

[UITableView issue when using separate delegate/dataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254354/uitableview-issue-when-using-separate-delegate-datasource)

[UITableView superClass for delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809576/uitableview-superclass-for-delegate)

[Getting “EXC_BAD_ACCESS” when accessing instance variable from within UITableView delegate method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450096/getting-exc-bad-access-when-accessing-instance-variable-from-within-uitableview)

[didSelectRowAtIndexPath generates EXC_BAD_ACCESS while willSelectRowAtIndexPath works fine UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414177/didselectrowatindexpath-generates-exc-bad-access-while-willselectrowatindexpath-w)

Comment: It might help to post the complete error message. Also, making an instance variable of type UITableViewController as a datasource for *another* table looks very fishy.

Comment: There's no error message, other than a stack dump. I set a breakpoint in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method and it gets there. However, the bad access happens at: 0x00fd009b  <+0015>  mov    0x8(%edx),%edi

Comment: also, I'm using Interface Builder to design the Views. I've dropped the UITableView into a UIView. The UITableViewController (pvc) gets data from a sqlite3 source during viewDidLoad. I'm open to suggestion for populating a UITableView as a component of a UIView.

Comment: If you are getting `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, you should probably add that code here.

Comment: It's doing nothing, just NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this line is crashing with EXC..:

self.tableView.delegate = pvc;

...did you hook up the tableView reference somewhere? In your code snippet "no" - but maybe you did in the NIB?

Comment: Yes, tried in NIB:
Outlet: DataSource -> Players To Draw...
Outlet: Delegate -> Players To Draw...
Referencing Outlets: view -> Players To Draw...

Comment: Got it. In NIB, I needed to drag a connection between the Table View Controller Object in the Objects list to the Referencing Outlet in the File's Owner (pvc) connection... in addition to the datasource and delegate connections. It's wired up and works.